# Phrase meaning "to justify themselves, even when they know that they're wrong"

Tags: phrase-request

What is the phrase that can be used to describe the situation when someone tries to justify himself, even when he knows that he's wrong.

The situation is when the person didn't complete his duty, and tries to explain that he did nothing wrong, by using lame excuses. So, my question is about doing something *incorrect* rather than doing something *morally* wrong.

It is not about internal reasoning, it is about someone trying to deflect blame being placed (rightly) on him by others.

Comment: When you say "even when they know they're wrong," do you mean "morally wrong?" Or just "incorrect?" Is this person trying to talk themselves into doing the wrong thing? Or talk themselves out of doing the wrong thing? A little more clarification would help quite a bit.

Comment: @J.R., I have updated my question, with the relevant information. Hope that now it is clear.

Comment: I would say that person is _trying to justify their actions_.

Comment: I think there is a further ambiguity between “reason with yourself” and “tries to explain”. The former is understood as an internal "conversation", while the latter is more likely to be an intentional deception of someone else. Are you asking about someone making himself feel better about a mistake or someone trying to deflect blame being placed 
(rightly) on him by others?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, I have updated the question to clarify your question.

Comment: Update point #2 totally contradicts both the question title and the introductory paragraph. So I'm still confused what exactly you want.

Comment: @Martha The missing element might actually be pretty close to the answer to the question. Certainly "explain yourself" and "explain themselves" would make this more clear, and in fact I would probably describe this person as "attempting to explain himself" or say that he "made a lame attempt to explain himself."

Comment: @Martha, I hadn't noticed the change in title. Someone had changed it. Now I have changed it to something descriptive.

Comment: @Gilles, Thankyou for the edit. Now the question is more clear. You have interpreted it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on point #2, I would say that he is trying to *[**pass the buck**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Pass+the+Buck)*:

> *Fig.* to pass the blame (to someone else); to give the responsibility (to someone else). *(source: The Free Dictionary)*

Comment: +1, Thankyou. It seems to fit my scenario clearly. Hoping to see some more answers, before I accept this one.

Answer (score 4):

In OP's context, if the person is trying to convince other people that's he's blameless, he might be...

> [**justifying**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/justify) himself
>    *to explain to someone the reason why you did something, especially when they think you have done something wrong*.

If he's trying to convince *himself*, one might say he's trying to...

> [**rationalise**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rationalize) his actions
>    *attempt to explain or justify (behaviour or an attitude) with logical reasons, even if these are not appropriate*.

Note that both verbs can also (but less commonly) be used in the other context.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. Is there any phrase that I can use to denote this scenario?

Comment: @saji89: I'm not sure what you mean by *phrase ... to denote this scenario*. As my answer implies, it's not clear to me from your question text whether you mean the person is attempting to convince *himself* that's he's not to blame (usually, *self-justification*), or to convince *others* of that (usually, *rationalisation*, though this term may be used to "explain away" *anything*, not just one's own possible guilt).

Comment: The question has not been edited, along with title. Is my question clear now?

Comment: @saji89: Well, comments to the question itself make it clear there are several possible meanings which are subtly different. But you yourself have endorsed Hellion's *pass the buck* - which isn't really about *justifying ones own actions* (except peripherally, in that it means assigning blame or responsibility for decision-making to someone else; by implication, the "buck-passer" *can't* be responsible, since someone else is). I think in the end you have to choose between "justifying" (the action was not wrong), and "deflecting blame" (it was wrong, but someone else's fault).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two previous scenarios. "Justifying", does define the "deflection" described. Saying that you did what you did because of a past experience is a "justification"!!!! No matter if you choose to recognize the behavior as wrong or not.                                              "I know what I did was bad, but I did it because someone did it to me." = JUSTIFICATION!!!

Comment: It's also rationalization.

Answer (score 0):

For a common (American) idiom, I think you would say that the person is trying to weasel out.